Can Whitney's Embedding Theorem be generalized for "smooth" spaces that locally look like an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb R^n$?
This is a follow up to this question. Let $M$ be a (regular?) Hausdorff second-countable topological space for which there is an $n$ such that every point $x\in M$ has a neighbourhood homeomorphic to some subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Furthermore, associate to $M$ a family $f_\alpha$ of homeomorphisms from subsets of $M$ to subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ such that the domains of those functions cover $M$ and the transition maps are smooth, analogous to how smooth manifolds are defined.
Is there a smooth embedding of $M$ into some $\mathbb R^k$?

How is this not exactly the Whitney embedding theorem?

@subrosar Isn't Whitney embedding theorem only for smooth manifolds? $\mathbb Q$ with the chart given by inclusion of $\mathbb Q$ into $\mathbb R$ will be an object in my sense but won't be a (smooth) manifold.

When you say the transition maps are smooth, you need to be a little careful, as their domains could be gnarly subsets of euclidean space. One way to make the definition precise is to say that they extend to smooth functions on some neighborhood in $\mathbb R^n$.
One obvious class of such spaces is simply arbitrary subsets of Euclidean space, which gives a sense of how complicated they might be, even though that  doesn't provide a counterexample.

@CheerfulParsnip That is much more restrictive than what i meant. I suppose you do need to keep the data of the embedding of the arbitrary subset into $\mathbb R^n$ to make what i meant precise tho. This will be more general than asking them to extend to smooth functions on an open (which is what i suppose you meant by neighbourhood?). For example the function from $\mathbb Q$ to itself that is $0$ for $x<\sqrt{2}$ and $1$ otherwise will be smooth in my sense but not in yours. An answer to your more restrictive question would be interesting too tho.

Charts need not intersect at all if they are not assumed you be open, so the "manifold" could be very pathological. I'm skeptical that you could guarantee much.

The problem is what is the definition of a smooth map on a non-open set? You can't take the derivative of a function if you don't have the room to do it. Think about the limit definition of derivative. It requires the function is defined in a neighborhood of the point.

@CheerfulParsnip We don't actually need a neighbourhood, it is enough for the point to be a limit point. But i think it would be fair to allow isolated points to be sent to arbitrary points and still call the function smooth.
